# How do I use Hogan-Express to compile an email template in an Express application?

Tags: node.js, email, hogan.js

I'm trying to use hogan-express to compile a html email template to send out in my node application. The basic example is a welcome email which sends a new user their login credentials. The html template is really simple and just outputs the data e.g.: {{username}} at the right points. The problem I'm having is I can't seem to fetch the compiled template as html to pass to nodemailer.

Based on robertlkep's really helpful post I have modified my code but still can't make the thing work. I can confirm that the following is in the app.js file:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('layout', 'layouts/default');
```

So the app is using that engine for all views and it's been working really well (didn't like Jade at all). The offending route has been changed to the following content:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var Report = require('../models/report');
var passport = require("passport");
var localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {

    // Registration logic etc

    var password = req.body.password;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var company = req.body.company;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var role = req.body.role;

    req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('company','Company field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render('register',{
           errors: errors,
           email: email,
           company: company,
           name: name,
           role: role 
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
           email: email,
           company: company,
           name: name,
           password: password,
           role: role
        });
        // Create User
        User.createUser(newUser, function(err,user){
            if (err) throw err;

            var textContent = 'You can log in at with your email address and this password: ' + password;

            app.render('emails/welcome', {
                layout:"layouts/email", 
                title: "Email Title",
                message:"Main Message",
                username: email, 
                password:password
            }, function(err,html) {

                if (err) throw err;

                console.log(html);

                var mailOptions = {
                    from:   'Test Email <test@test.co.uk>',
                    to:     email,
                    subject:'Subject',
                    text:   textContent,
                    html:   html
                };

                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
                    host: 'smtp.host.co.uk',
                    port: 465,
                    secure:true,
                    auth: {
                        user: 'test@test.co.uk',
                        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
                    }
                })); 

                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error,info) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        req.flash('error', "Emailed failed");

                        res.location('/users');
                        res.redirect('/users');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                        // Send flash message
                        req.flash('success', "New user created");

                        res.location('/users');
                        res.redirect('/users');
                    };
                });

            });                          
        });
    };
});
```

I've stripped out anything too specific from it, I don't really send emails out from test@test.com. Anyway, using this code the user is created but the html doesn't get logged to the console and the app just hangs. I'm still pretty new to Node so what stupid newbie mistake have I made?

Answer (score 2):

`hogan-express` is an Express templating engine. If you want to use it, you have to set it up properly first:

```
// assuming that `app` is your Express app instance
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
```

If you want to render a template and capture the generated HTML, you can then use [`app.render()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.render):

```
app.render('emails/welcome', { ... }, function(err, html) {
  ...
});
```

(alternatively, if `app` isn't in scope, you can use `res.render()` as well)

This assumes that you're actually *using* Express. If not, just use [`hogan.js`](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js) as using `hogan-express` doesn't make much sense in that situation.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer but I'm still not quite there. I've amended the question to include some more info and your suggestions.

Comment: @Taintedmedialtd does `app` actually exist at the point there you're using it? If not, use `res.render()` instead of `app.render()` (although I would have assumed that the app would have crashed because you're using an undefined variable, unless something in your app is ignoring exceptions being thrown).